# Mismatched Character Highlighting in Chrome Browser Search

Tags: html, google-chrome, unicode, cjk

During a search on a Japanese text page in Chrome, [link](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml), I experienced an unexpected result. I used the `⌘+f` function to search for `ﾑ` (Unicode 0xFF91) character. Chrome, however, highlighted `ム` (Unicode 0x30E0) and `む` (Unicode 0x3080) in yellow.

**Why Chrome is highlighting char with different unicodes for a search of different unicode char?**

[image]
PS: search for `ﾑ` on this page.

Comment: I don't know Google search algorithm exactly; however, all following *Letter Mu* found: - `ﾑ` (U+FF91,  *Halfwidth Katakana Letter Mu*)
- `ム` (U+30E0,  *Katakana Letter Mu*)
- `む` (U+3080,  *Hiragana Letter Mu*)